# AJAX call to Slack URL not working on Safari browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, proxy, safari, slack

[I am behind a corporate proxy]

I have following AJAX post request which submits the text on Slack Channel.

When I do it from Chrome it works just fine. But when I do it on Safari for iOS emulator the code doesn't work.

```
   $.ajax({

    data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
        "text" : com,
        "channel" : "testing1",
        "username" : "FST_"+cat,
        "icon_emoji" : icon
    }),

    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
             console.log("Moving to new page, LOG: "+data)
              window.location.href = "record.html";
          }

});
```

I tried to add proxy header but that didn't help.
New to slack API.

Comment: Seams to me more like a Safari specific issue and not related the proxy configuration. Apparently others have problems with AJAX under Safari too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626620/ajax-append-not-working-correctly-on-safari-ios-osx

Comment: Do you get any error messages? I would also recommend adding the error function to see if you get anything

Answer (score 0):

My Organization has proxy enabled. I added proxy as an optional parameter and it solved the issue.